# Выборка данных из двух таблиц MySQL

Tags: mysql

Нужна помощь.. чувствую что решение простое, но туплю уже не первый час..
Делаю трекер привычек..

Две таблицы вида:

Table **habbits**

```
id | int | 1
user_id | int | 2
title | varchar| Отжимания
```

**habbit_data**

```
id | int | 1
habbit_id | int | 1
user_id | int | 2
counts | int | 25
date | int | 2023-03-03
```

Нужно выбрать все данные из habbits и данные из habbits_data за определенный день.
Проблема в том, что если за какой-то день в habbits_data нет данных, то и habbit.title не цепляется.

Пробовал и простым запросом вида

```
SELECT * FROM Habbit_data, Habbits WHERE Habbits.id = Habbit_data.habbit_id and date='2023-03-03';
```

и через JOIN - не выходит цветок камменный.. цепляется title только если есть дата за текущий день. h[ttps://disk.yandex.ru/i/WNeBQlRS5lhi6Q](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/WNeBQlRS5lhi6Q)

можно костылем решить вопрос - выбрать дополнительно более раннюю дату и потом перебирать массив https://disk.yandex.ru/i/S6iKOQAREI8QDw

но хотелось бы правильный запрос. Как результат мне нужны habbits.title и habbit_data.date даже если date нет т.е.

id | title | date | status or counts

1. Зарядка - 2023.03.03 - 1
2. Отжимания - 2023.03.03 - 25
3. Медитация - NULL - NULL

Comment: *если за какой-то день в habbits_data нет данных, то и habbit.title не цепляется.* Последствия неправильного типа связывания (да ещё в устаревшей синтаксической форме, через запятую). Используйте явный LEFT JOIN - и всё получится.

Comment: Сейчас как раз и стоит JOIN - не получается через него )

select t1.*, t2.* from `Habbit_data` t1 left join `habbits` t2 on `t2`.`id` = `t1`.`habbit_id` where `t2`.`user_id` = 2 and `t1`.`date` = '2023-03-03' order by `habbit_id` asc

 https://disk.yandex.ru/i/5zt1ZoMZD9b5sA

Comment: удалите дату или сделайте интервал, вы сами ограничиваете свой выбор. Уточните в итоговой ID это что за ID какой таблицы?

Comment: Дату удалять нельзя - мне нужны данные за конкретный день.
Интервал - тоже не вариант.. не даст title если не будет записи во habbit_data
На данном скрине оба ID, от двух таблиц.. но это не принципиально сейчас.. 

Как вариант - делать 2 запроса и не ломать мозг.. Но интересно именно решение в одном запросе.

Comment: *Сейчас как раз и стоит JOIN - не получается через него* В тексте вопроса этого нет. А предложение сходить на сторонний ресурс по ссылке - это далеко не лучшее, что Вы могли бы предложить. Вопрос должен быть самодостаточным и не зависеть от чьего-то желания удалить с яндекс-диска ненужные ЕМУ материалы. Ну и ознакомьтесь с этой темой: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035)